# @property automatically generates 15+ methods (Xcode 8.0, Obj-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Creating some property automatically generates 15+ strange methods, listed below:
[image]
[image]
These are **also** created for **primitive** properties (such as `BOOL`, `NSInteger`, etc).

All of the above methods are `void`, but there are lots of others too:
[image]
[image]
[image]
Well, `setMyView:` and `myView` methods are obvious, but what about all the rest?

So here are the questions:

1) Is there are documentation for these?

2) Should developers use them at all?

3) How can these be useful?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't implemented these methods yourself, they are probably generated as part of KVC/KVO compliance for this property. Which is weird since Apple officially doesn't support KVC/KVO on iOS platform unless specifically stated.

More at [Key Value programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1).

Answer (score -1):

It's not generating methods for you, it's autocompleting with methods that contain the string "myView" or parts of it. Since it knows that you're creating a method, it's giving you suggestions for existing methods containing that string

Comment: I thought it is obvious that the whole point of my question is that I did not specifically generate those methods by myself. And it would be great if you could first open Xcode and test your answer before sharing the ideas...

Comment: I know you didn't generate the methods yourself, it's how I interpreted the questions based on the screenshots, and yes I see the same results when I follow your example.